# How do I get data out of Mongo using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Running into problems getting any data out of mongo using mongoose.  The connection seems fine as i've got debugging statements that are being printed out.  I've searched high and low for what could be causing this but afaik I'm setting up the schema and collections fine.

here's what i have in a file called posts.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sister', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;}  //this does not get printed
);

mongoose.connection.on("open", function(){
  console.log("mongodb is connected")}  //this gets printed
);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var thePost = new Schema({
        name : String
});

mongoose.model('post', thePost);
var posts = db.model('post');

posts.find({}, [], function(err, calls) { 
  console.log(err, calls, calls.length);  //prints out: null [] 0
});
```

To seed the data, I've done this in my mongo shell, which inserts a document and then shows that find all can find it:

```
> randumb = { name : 'emile' };
{ "name" : "emile" }
> db.post.insert(randumb);
> db.post.find({});      
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e775e8cc24f31883fdafbab"), "name" : "emile" }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
var posts = db.model('post');
```

to

```
var posts = mongoose.model('post');
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it even shorter, try and change:

```
mongoose.model('post', thePost);
var posts = db.model('post');
```

to:

```
var posts = mongoose.model('post', thePost);
```